# The complete list of programming Language Analyzers?

Tags: programming-languages, analyzer

For Delphi developers, a company called [Peganza](http://www.peganza.com/) created two useful sourcecode analysers: [Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.htm) and [Pascal Browser](http://www.peganza.com/products_pab.htm). I don't use them that often but when a project is close to it's deadline, they are useful to find some of the last minor issues.

There are probably a lot more code analyzers for Pascal. And for C++, C#, Java, VB.NET, Ruby, SQL, XSLT, Django, Forth, Perl, PHP and any other language that mankind has discovered, developed or created. Thus, it would be nice to have a long list of those here at SO, as a Wiki. Then visitors just have to check one location. :-)

Two kinds of tools will qualify for this list:
1) Tools which analyse code and report statistics and/or possible design errors.
2) Tools which turn code into readable or browse-able reports with indices and overviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source static analyzer for C and Objective-C at http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org. It's also part of Xcode.